# Springboot doesn't work except when hello is typed

Tags: java, spring-boot

I created a very simply SpringBoot project using my groupId and artifactId. Looks like it doesn't want to kick off and some mappings are missing. But when I use the same package names and classnames as the SPring Boot tutorial which is on spring.io site, it works.

My POM is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>firstspringboot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->

<parent>

    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>

</parent>

<properties>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>junit</groupId>

        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My Resource 'Greeting'

```
package com.my.spring.firstspringboot.entities;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Greeting {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Greeting() {

    }
    public Greeting(String firstName, String lastName) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setId(new StringBuilder().append(SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").nextInt()).append("_").append(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("{\n\"name\":\"").append(this.firstName).append(" ").append(this.lastName).append("\"\n").append(",").append("{\n\"id\":\"").append(this.id).append("\"").toString();
    }
}
```

And its Controller:

```
package com.my.spring.firstspringboot.controllers;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.my.spring.firstspringboot.entities.Greeting;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Welcome!";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(name="name",defaultValue="John") String name) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return new Greeting(name,name);
    }

}
```

And main App

```
package com.my.spring.firstspringboot.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App

{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

    }

}
```

Is there something more that I need to do here? I thought it's simply a boot and autoconfigure by default.

Comment: Please provide the error message

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar       It's a 404 not found. It doesn't even hit the controller class.

Comment: Change RequestMapping to GetMapping

Comment: Put your Application class in the package com.my.spring.firstspringboot. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar  I don't think that's the issue here. RequestMapping and RequestController have been designed to automatically handle certain web application based configs. I believe this is due to some inconsistence in package or resource lookup

Comment: @ha9u63ar with RequestMapping you have to explicitly define method=RequestMethod.GET as in the answer below. You have a simple controller at the level of main SpringBootApplication, componentscan should pick up all the classes.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar     No you don't have to explicitly do that. By default, everything is a GET in Spring webmvc servlet design.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add http method in your requestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

or try removing first endpoint which you have declared with path "/"

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (Thanks to @JBNizet for pointing that out), I needed to keep my main application under the package name `com.my.spring.firstspringboot`

The reason is that Spring looks immediately under the `firstspringboot` subpackage to find the execution class since it's the artifact ID.

The correct approach should probably be the following:

1) Keep the app runner class in higher subpackage than resource/controller classes.

e.g `com.my.firstapplication.App`, `com.my.firstapplication.resources.Resource` etc.

2) If I rely on manual settings, use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`

3) If I am relying on Spring to do it - it's `@SpringBootApplication`